# Regarding trace of idempotent matrix multiplied by its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Suppose $M$ is a $n$ by $n$ idempotent real matrix of rank $p$, and therefore of trace $p$. Is there anything obvious we can say about the trace of $M^TM$ in terms of $p$? Note $M$ is not necessarily an orthogonal projection so $M \neq M^T$ in general.

Comment: Do you know about the Jordan Normal form of a linear map?

Comment: I already tried writing $P=Q^{-1}MQ$ where $P$ is a diagonal matrix with the first $p$ diagonal entries $1$, the rest $0$ and I got as far as $tr(M^TM)=tr(A^{-1}PAP)$ where $A=Q^TQ$, so it seemed like $tr(M^TM)=p$ if $A$ and $P$ commutes but I don't think that's generally true? Just doing cyclic permutations of $A^{-1}PAP$ inside trace doesn't seem to make $A$ and $A^{-1}$ cancel with one another.

Comment: what don't you do this yourself for the $2\times 2$ case of an upper triangular matrix with a 0 and a 1 on its diagonal.

Comment: Yeah I already tried some simple examples and it didn't give me a 'nice' answer (the trace seems to be much larger than $p$ in some cases), but I thought it might be worth asking in case there is. Your answer seem to suggest there isn't though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p=0$ and $p=n$ this is trivial, since there is only one idempotent of rank $p$.

**Claim:** Let $1\le p< n$ be integers.
The range of $M\longmapsto\mathrm{Tr}(M^TM)$ is equal to $[p,+\infty)$ when $M$ runs over the set of all $n\times n$ real idempotents of rank $p$.

**Sketch of proof:**

- By continuity and connectedness, the range is an interval.
- Easy examples show that the range contains $[p,+\infty)$.
- Given an arbitrary idempotent $M$ of rank $p$, the characteristic polynomial of $M$ is $(X-1)^pX^{n-p}$.
  Since it splits over $\mathbb{R}$, we can find an orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $N=P^TMP$ is upper triangular with a diagonal made of $n-p$ zeros and $p$ ones. It follows that
  $$\mathrm{Tr}(M^TM)=\mathrm{Tr}(N^TN)\ge 1^2+\cdots+1^2=p$$
  and the proof is complete.